# How to use eval and echo in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

This is my simple script to find server's IP and check if it resolves from the server:

```
read domain_name
echo domain is: $domain_name
def_ip="ip route get 8.8.8.8 | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 7"
if ( dig +short @8.8.8.8 $domain_name == $def_ip )
then
    echo $domain_name resolves from $def_ip
else
    echo $domain_name does not resolve from $def_ip, please check
fi
```

This is the error after running:

```
google.com
domain is: google.com
setup_libs()
setup_system()
create_search_list()
ndots is 1.
get_server_list()
make_server(8.8.8.8)
make_server(127.0.0.53)
dig_query_setup
parse_args()
making new lookup
make_empty_lookup()
digrc (open)
main parsing +short
main parsing @8.8.8.8
make_server(8.8.8.8)
main parsing google.com
clone_lookup()
make_empty_lookup()
clone_server_list()
make_server(8.8.8.8)
looking up google.com
main parsing ==
clone_lookup()
make_empty_lookup()
clone_server_list()
make_server(8.8.8.8)
looking up ==
main parsing ip
clone_lookup()
make_empty_lookup()
clone_server_list()
make_server(8.8.8.8)
looking up ip
main parsing route
clone_lookup()
make_empty_lookup()
clone_server_list()
make_server(8.8.8.8)
looking up route
main parsing get
clone_lookup()
make_empty_lookup()
clone_server_list()
make_server(8.8.8.8)
looking up get
main parsing 8.8.8.8
clone_lookup()
make_empty_lookup()
clone_server_list()
make_server(8.8.8.8)
looking up |
main parsing head
clone_lookup()
make_empty_lookup()
clone_server_list()
make_server(8.8.8.8)
looking up head
main parsing -1
Invalid option: -1
Usage:  dig [@global-server] [domain] [q-type] [q-class] {q-opt}
            {global-d-opt} host [@local-server] {local-d-opt}
            [ host [@local-server] {local-d-opt} [...]]

Use "dig -h" (or "dig -h | more") for complete list of options
echo google.com does not resolve from ip route get 8.8.8.8 | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 7, please check
```

If I change `echo $domain_name does not resolve from $def_ip` to `eval $domain_name ...`, the error is that command `google.com` is not found.

I searched and based on results I think I should use both `echo` and `eval` but did not find a proper way to do that.

Is that right? If not, what's the best practice for this?

Comment: can you first try to explain what you want to achieve ? it would be more useful than debating on the error you got. try to simplify everything as its concept.

Comment: @dominix I'm trying to generate Let's Encrypt certificate after checking if the entered domain resolves from the server

Comment: your question has nothing to do with letsencrypt. please reformulate : what are you trying to do in this script ?

Comment: @dominix, I know. The issue is the lines I entered in the question. If I pass this, I think I'll have no issues with other lines.

Comment: so you want to compare IP address ? just put an IP address into a variables then compares variables.

Comment: @dominix yes, that's right.

Comment: The answers you got so far address and fix severe errors, but there's more. Please see [*Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in `bash`/POSIX shells*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/108618) *and* links therein, [*Understanding `IFS= read -r line`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618) and [*Why is `printf` better than `echo`?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks Kamil, I'm reading them and learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture the output of a command, you need Command Substitution `$( ... )`.

```
def_ip=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 7)
```

To compare two values, you can't use `( ... )`, it just runs the command in the background. Use `[ ... ]` or `[[ ... ]]`:

```
if [ "$(dig +short @8.8.8.8 "$domain_name")" = "$def_ip" ] ; then
#or
if [[ $(dig +short @8.8.8.8 "$domain_name") = "$def_ip" ]] ; then
```

Do you notice we used command substitution again?

With `[[ ... ]]`, double quotes aren't needed on the left hand side of the comparison. They might still be needed on the right hand side to prevent interpreting it as a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
IPLOCAL=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 7)
IPDNS=$(dig +short @8.8.8.8 "$domain")
if [[ "$IPLOCAL" == "IPDNS" ]] ; then ...
```